# is there any way to simplify this line?

Tags: f#

```
if reelID = reelWeights.Count - 1
    then Array.fold calc1 (0L,0) reelWeights.[reelID]
    else Array.fold calc2 (0L,0) reelWeights.[reelID]
```

I tried use pipeline, it seems to slow down a little bit (not sure why):

```
reelWeights.[reelID]
    |> (if reelID = reelWeights.Count - 1 then Array.fold calc1 else Array.fold calc2) (0L,0)
```

if I do

```
let calc x = if x then calc1 else calc2
Array.fold (calc reelID = reelWeights.Count - 1) (0L,0) reelWeights.[reelID]
```

then it looks nice at the cost of redundantly check conditionion in loops.

Comment: The first approach is fast and readable. How do you want to *simplify* it?

Comment: @pad hmm, i thought there might be better ways so that i don't have to type same parameters twice. if it turns out to be silly question i will delete it shortly.

Comment: In any case, questions like this are better suited for [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `calc1` and `calc2` have the same signature (or if they're values rather than functions, are the same type):

```
let calc = if reelID = reelWeights.Count - 1 then calc1 else calc2
Array.fold calc (0L, 0) reelWeights.[reelID]
```

Comment: it's not called functional for nothing !

Answer (score 1):

Or in one line:

```
let weight = 
    Array.fold (if reelID = (reelWeights.Count - 1) then calc1 else calc2) (0L,0) reelWeights.[reelID]
```